# Is there software that can write song music?

Tags: music, mp3, audacity, musescore

I'm looking for software (Ubuntu) to which I could input some song mp3 file and which would display the notes of the song, (like dots on a music sheet, not like the wavy lines of Audacity).

I would like to teach myself to sing in tune.

There are many sites online which show music sheets, but they always show the partitions for the music of a song, not for the song itself (the vocals). And some don't display partitions at all, only guitar chords which I don't understand.

I currently use musescore. I listen to the song, then I try to hum it, then I try to input the notes one by one in musescore. I don't always succeed, and since I sing out of tune I'm afraid I'm sometimes teaching myself to keep on singing out of tune. For me, this process is really slow and error-prone. There's got to be some software somewhere which would make a better job of doing this.

If I could only see the notes, I could copy them in musecore, then create an mp3 file with the music of the vocals, and try to sing along with that.

I enjoy singing, but, if I do it when somebody else is present, this person will quickly ask me "would you like me to put some music on?" or start talking to me to make me stop singing without actually saying "shut up". So.

Karaoke sites are useless, they keep the music of the instruments and remove the music of the vocals. It's the reverse I would need.

Audacity has a filter supposed to do this but it doesn't function. And anyway it never displays notes, only curly lines.

Any suggestion welcome.

Comment: Paid software https://www.lunaverus.com/download 30 day trial and a 1 time $39.00 license fee but they do support Linux. "Audacity has a filter supposed to do this but it doesn't function."  Yes it does but you need to convert to MIDI.

Comment: Sounds like a case for search terms like "app recognize vocal pitch". A few years ago, I have searched for an Android app to recognize the pitch of sung vocals. There were apps that do that, many called "tuner" and variations thereof, but none worked as well as I had hoped it to. At the risk of sounding melodramatic: The human voice is a complex instrument. It can be surprisingly difficult to determine the intended pitch of sung speech.